# undefined method `url' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to RoR.

I just download some sample codes and deploy the app.
After that, I get error message as follows:

```
undefined method `url' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #5):

2: 
3: <p>
4:   <b>Url:</b>
5:   <%= @page.url %>
6: </p>
7:
```

And the corresponding codes in pages_controller.rb is

```
def index 
  @pages = Page.all
  respond_with(@pages)
end
```

Is there any suggestion for handling this error?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborating on @Lakitu's answer a bit, you should have something like this in your index view:

```
<% for page in @pages do %>
  <p><b>Url:</b> <%= page.url %></p>
<% end %>
```

Don't know why scaffolding produced this issue, but the root cause is very well explained by @Lakitu (+1 for that).

Comment: I just find out i try to access /pages/show for getting index datas. It is not an issue about Scaffold. It's an issue about my brain :'(. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You are referencing `@page` in your view, but you're passing `@pages` from the controller. The `index` method is usually used for lists of items, your view seems to better be used as a `show` view.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I use scaffold to create this. And index is used for lists of items actually.

Comment: Thanks! thumb up to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done the db instalation? 
rake db:create
rake db:migrate

Comment: Thanks for reply. The db and table are existed actually.